# Percent-Encoding url issue in swift 3

Tags: objective-c, swift, encoding, swift2, swift3

For percent-encoding, i'm using the below code which is working fine.

```
string.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!)
```

But sometimes i'm getting encoded url from server. So i think the url getting encoded twice on using the above code which creates a problem.

How can i manage this ?

Comment: Try to decode it before encoding it, if it succeeds, don't encode again.

Comment: @EricAya I think i need to identify if it's encoded or not because sometimes i'm getting url with spaces .

Comment: You cannot determine reliably if a string is already percent encoded or not. How would you decide if `%2B` is the percent encoding of "+" or the string "%2B"?